# Overcoming needle haystack confusion in PHP

Tags: php, language-design

What is the most practical way of overcoming needle haystack confusion in PHP?

Here $needle is the first argument

```
bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
```

Here $needle is the second argument

```
string strstr ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, bool $before_needle = false ] )
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1672543

Comment: @Gordon, I swapped this function list with the internal array from `get_defined_functions()`, and found that this list misses the mb string functions and the iconv ones.  But it's still neat ;-?

Comment: Parahat, this is just one of many facets which underline the fact that PHP evolved rather than was born of a clean redesign.  The multiple function naming conventions is another.

Comment: @Gordon That's very handy, thanks.

Comment: Based on Gordon's link: String functions are haystack, needle and array functions are needle, haystack.

Comment: I experimented with a Str class that unifies the order to "needle, haystack": https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Lib/Utility/Str.php  Didnt check the performance overhead or speed loss here, though.

Comment: There is no confusion. String functions begin with the haystack and array functions with the needle.

Answer (score 12):

it might make sense if you think of this as pre-fix representation of an in-fix operations.

```
is "bat" in array ("cat", "rat", "bat", "fat")
is $needle in_array $haystack
in_array($needle, $haystack)


does "supercalifragistic" string contain string "percal"
does $haystack strstr $needle
strstr($haystack, $needle)
```

Comment: But string is an array of characters. **<?php $str = "foo"; echo $str[2]; ?>**

Comment: But why would the sentence `does $haystack strstr $needle` be more logical then `is $needle strstr $haystack` ?

Comment: @Nanne more about mnemonic than logic.  the statement 'is x in y' has 'in', and therefore in_array first param will be x and second will be y.  in the sentence with the 'does', the y is before the x. so the function would take y first and then x.

Comment: @Nanne You have to think of what the function means, we all have our own ways in coding, whoever built this php function was a human and strstr sounds like they were thinking of meta str function, so str(str(... It kinda makes sense... strpos= does string have a position... if it were posstr() yeah It wouldnt make sense but the order of the little keywords helps and one as a native english speaker cant help read it like that... strrchr can't be easily read as is charecter in string.... rathe rit is does string have character.... pay attention to the order of these function names.

Answer (score 6):

I made a cheat sheet for all php commands containing needle haystack parameters.

String functions are haystack/needle:

```
          strpos $haystack, $needle
         stripos $haystack, $needle
          strstr $haystack, $needle
          strchr $haystack, $needle
         stristr $haystack, $needle
         strrchr $haystack, $needle
        strripos $haystack, $needle
         strrpos $haystack, $needle
    substr_count $haystack, $needle

strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] ) : int
stripos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] ) : int
strstr ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, bool $before_needle = FALSE ] ) : string
(same as strstr) strchr ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, bool $before_needle = FALSE ] ) : string
stristr ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, bool $before_needle = FALSE ] ) : string
strrchr ( string $haystack , mixed $needle ) : string
strripos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] ) : int
strrpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] ) : int
substr_count ( string $haystack , string $needle [, int $offset = 0 [, int $length ]] ) : int
```

Array functions are needle/haystack (except array_filter):

```
    array_search $needle, $haystack
        in_array $needle, $haystack

in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] ) : bool
array_search ( mixed $needle  , array $haystack  [, bool $strict  ] )
```

array_filter ( array $array [, callable $callback [, int $flag = 0 ]] ) : array

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that's important. It's the same with the Linux bash. For example tar uses arguments archive files but ln uses arguments target linkname. But my example isn't a programming language so here is another explanation: What was the first in the world counting or numbering? For what you need it's always 2 arguments. The same is true for my example with tar and ln.

Comment: I feel issues with inconsistencies like this is what made me leave PHP for other languages so for the learner, mnemonics and help with issues like that can be very important.

Comment: @Zev: IMO numbering and counting isn't PHP specific.