# How to remove space from $_FILES?

Tags: php

I have this code of images pre-upload:

```
    $tf = $directory . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'][0];
```

I would remove any spaces in the parameter ['name']. Can I embed this code or not? I tried it with tim () but I can not.

Comment: `preg_replace($tf, '/\s+/', '')` or `str_replace($tf, ' ', '')` if it's only spaces (no tabs) which i don't think are valid in filenames anyway.

Comment: Can you show the code you have written for removing spaces so far?

Comment: @Mark preg_replace($tf, '/\s+/', '') won't work it should have been preg_replace('/s+/', '', $tf) This is another example of argument confusions we often experience when using PHP functions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260589/overcoming-needle-haystack-confusion-in-php

Comment: @ParahatMelayev: I figured there was a good chance I got the order wrong, but I wasn't going to look it up. That's an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: preg_replace($tf, '/\s+/', '') don't work. ['name'] is the name of the file and i would remove any spaces. Pphpdev, i try with  trim(['name']) but don't work.

Comment: I stand corrected. @FilippoAlessi: http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php Look it up. I got the order of arguments wrong. It should have been `preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $tf)` as Parahat points out. We're willing to help you, but please meet us half way. If you don't understand what a piece of code does, or is supposed to do, don't try it blindly.

Comment: Excuse me, i'm not expert .I saw that if I try to remove the spaces with preg_replace or str_replace hangs the entire upload. Maybe I'm wrong, maybe this is not the right method to rename a file ...

Comment: Maybe I was unclear, sorry. Should I rename the file before uploading in order to remove the spaces.

Comment: I solved differently. Rename each file after upload ... Thanks anyway, thanks mates!

Comment: This is pretty late, but it might help others if you posted your own solution here as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:

```
$tf = $directory . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'][0];
$tf = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$tf);
```